# Javascript auto-generate list from database records

Tags: javascript, node.js

I think I'm being dumb and this is really simple.  I'm trying to create a Javascript list that looks something like the following:

```
var sitemap = sm.createSitemap({
    hostname: hostname,
    cacheTime: 600000,  //600 sec (10 min) cache purge period 
    urls: [
        { url: '/' , changefreq: 'weekly', priority: 0.8, lastmodrealtime: true, lastmodfile: 'views/home.hbs' },
        { url: 'photo/image_id1', changefreq: 'weekly', priority: 0.8, lastmodrealtime: true},
        { url: 'photo/image_id2', changefreq: 'weekly', priority: 0.8, lastmodrealtime: true},
        { url: 'photo/image_id3', changefreq: 'weekly', priority: 0.8, lastmodrealtime: true}
        ...
    ]
});
```

In order to auto-generate the bottom 3 URLs I'm using the following:

```
function photoURLs() {
    var siteMapArray = new Array();
    db.sequelize.query(photoQuery, {
        replacements: queryParams
    }).spread(function(makeSiteMap) {

        //console.log(makeSiteMap);

        makeSiteMap.forEach(function(obj) {
            siteMapArray.push({
                url: '/photo/' + obj.img_id,
                changefreq: 'weekly',
                priority: 0.8,
                lastmodrealtime: true
            }, );
        });

        //console.log (siteMapArray);
    })
    return siteMapArray
}

var sitemap = sm.createSitemap({
    hostname: hostname,
    cacheTime: 600000, //600 sec (10 min) cache purge period 
    urls: [{
            url: '/',
            changefreq: 'weekly',
            priority: 0.8,
            lastmodrealtime: true,
            lastmodfile: 'views/home.hbs'
        },
        photoURLs()
    ]
});
```

This isn't working.  Everything returned ion photoURLs is ignored but I'm not sure how to modify the return

**EDIT**

if I put `console.log({url: '/photo/' + obj.img_id, changefreq: 'weekly', priority: 0.8, lastmodrealtime: true },)` directly after the `siteMapArray.push` command I get output like the following, which I think is what I'm after.

```
  { url: '/photo/354F5745AF',
    changefreq: 'weekly',
    priority: 0.8,
    lastmodrealtime: true },
  { url: '/photo/8CC02E33C0',
    changefreq: 'weekly',
    priority: 0.8,
    lastmodrealtime: true },
  { url: '/photo/ED243618FA',
    changefreq: 'weekly',
    priority: 0.8,
    lastmodrealtime: true },
```

Comment: Is it intentional that the desired output contains the path `photos/image_id1` while the code only appears to generate `/photo/1`? Hard to say - you're relying on data you're not showing us...

Comment: No, that was a typo - what data would you like?  The first example produces output for each row but the second doesn't.

Comment: Well, the stuff that `obj.img_id` will actually hold seems important. As it stands - it's impossible to know if it's a simple integer like 1, 2, 3 or if it's 'image_id1', 'image_id2', 'image_id3' etc. - We can't see your hard-disk or screen and puzzling.stackexchange is a place where people are interested in guessing - here, not so much. ;)

Comment: I've been trying to sort through this and I can see that at the point in my code where I have `console.log(siteMapArray)` I seem to have a full array of data, but at the point `return siteMapArray`, it is empty.  Why and how do I resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised my issue was the Promise hadn't resolved so I've rewritten to code as below.  I'm sure it isn't the best code, but it works.  (The bit about tags is new).

```
function createSiteMap(myURLs, tagURLs) {
    var sitemap = sm.createSitemap({
        hostname: hostname,
        cacheTime: 600000,  //600 sec (10 min) cache purge period 
        urls: myURLs
        });
    fs.writeFileSync("public/sitemap.xml", sitemap.toString());    
    process.exit();
}

function uniq(a) {
    var seen = {};
    return a.filter(function(item) {
        return seen.hasOwnProperty(item) ? false : (seen[item] = true);
    });
}

function getPhotos() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var siteMapArray = new Array()
        var tags = new Array()
        siteMapArray.push ({ url: '/' , changefreq: 'weekly', priority: 0.8, lastmodrealtime: true, lastmodfile: 'views/home.hbs' },)
        db.sequelize.query(photoQuery, {
            replacements: queryParams
        }).spread(function(makeSiteMap) {
            makeSiteMap.forEach(function(obj) {
                var siteLink = { url: '/photo/' + obj.img_id, changefreq: 'weekly', priority: 0.6, lastmodrealtime: true }
                siteMapArray.push(siteLink);
                obj.tags = obj.tags.split(',').map(function(e) {
                    return e.trim();
                });
                for (var tag in obj.tags) {
                    tags.push(obj.tags[tag])
                }
            });

            resolve (siteMapArray);

            var uniqueTags = uniq(tags);
            for (var tag in uniqueTags) {
                var siteLink = { url: '/search/' + uniqueTags[tag], changefreq: 'weekly', priority: 0.8, lastmodrealtime: true }
                siteMapArray.push (siteLink);
            }

            createSiteMap(siteMapArray);

        });
    });
};
```